# How to get Jscroll plugin ajax response in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-jscroll

> Trying to get jscroll response in callback function, looking for url received in response, so that it can be updated on scrolling and get page view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.next-btncall').jscroll({
    debug: false,
    autoTrigger: true,
    autoTriggerUntil: false,
    loadingHtml: '<img src="/static/images/loading.svg" alt="Loading" /> Loading...',
    loadingFunction: false,
    padding: 20,
    nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
    contentSelector: '.endless-col',
    pagingSelector: '',
    callback: urlUpdate(data)
});
function urlUpdate(contentSelector) {
    console.log('responose of ajax');
    window.history.pushState(null, null, url);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$('.next-btncall').jscroll({
    contentSelector: '.endless-col',
    callback: function(data) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, data.replace(' .endless-col', ''));
    }
});`